# ViewRenderable not working ARCore

Tags: android, arcore

I initialized a ViewRenderable in the following way:

```
ViewRenderable.builder()
            .setView(context, R.layout.fifabanner)
            .build()
            .thenAccept(renderable ->{
              bannerRenderable = renderable;
              bannerRenderable.setPixelsToMetersRatio(500);
              Toast.makeText(context,Float.toString(bannerRenderable.getPixelsToMetersRatio()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
```

The view xml file is the following:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/planetInfoCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/fifa_ad"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dp" />
```

I attached the view to a node.

```
localPosition.set(0.01f * image.getExtentX(), 0.01f, 0.01f * image.getExtentZ());
    cornerNode = new Node();
    cornerNode.setParent(this);
    cornerNode.setLocalPosition(localPosition);
    cornerNode.setRenderable(bannerRenderable);
```

However, out of 30 tries or so, the ad only appeared once. Please note that I am scanning an image and then only displaying the ad.
What am I doing wrong here and what must I change?

Comment: Did you try transforming the object *after* adding the renderable? Also. Try it with a TransformableNode. I had a similar problem with transformations until I used TransformableNode.

Answer (score 0):

Change your XML file to the following:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/planetInfoCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/fifa_ad"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:padding="6dp" />
```

and, change localposition.set() as:

```
localPosition.set(-0.0f * image.getExtentX(), 0.1f, +0.5f * image.getExtentZ());
cornerNode = new Node();
cornerNode.setParent(this);
cornerNode.setLocalPosition(localPosition);
cornerNode.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(-1f, 0, 0), 90f));
cornerNode.setRenderable(bannerRenderable);
```